# 'World Cup' or 'world cup' in these particular contexts

Tags: capitalization

1. The **Under-19 World Cup** takes place every 4 years.
2. The **2014 FIFA World Cup** takes in Brazil.
3. He is the highest scorer in the **world cup history**.
4. **Cricket world cups** are fun.

Lastly, what to do when you refer to it for the **second time** in the same paragraph.

1. The 2015 Cricket World Cup takes place in Oceania. Australia will go into the **world cup** as favourites.

Am I right in referring to them this way?

Answer (score 1):

World Cup is a proper noun in all of these contexts, so would be capitalised e.g.

> He is the highest scorer in World Cup history

The only example I can think of that wouldn't be capitalised is if you weren't referring to one individual sport's world cup, but many:

> Ireland competed in world cups in many sports including football, rugby, and sailing.

However, that said, it would probably be acceptable if you capitalised it in that sentence as well.

You would still capitalise it on its second inclusion in a paragraph, the same way you would capitalise 'October' or 'John' every single time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a case of when or how many times you refer to it; it's a matter of whether *it* is simply a *noun* -- a general word for some *thing* -- or a Proper Noun -- the name of *the* thing. (Notice that I only capitalized "Proper Noun" for effect -- it should not normally be capitalized!)

When writing about any sport's international championship event that is called the World Cup of ... within that sport's culture, you should capitalize the name of the event. If you were writing about drinking vessels around the globe, admittedly a very contrived example, one might talk about regional tankards, local mugs, world cups.